# Escaping @ characters in /etc/postfix/virtual not working for 'reject_sender_login_mismatch'

Tags: postfix

****TLDR;** Only if I remove the backslash characters in my mapping, I can use the reject_sender_login_mismatch functionality...**

I need to escape some @ characters in my **/etc/postfix/virtual** mapping because of some (unknown) reasons. And everything worked till so far...

Now, I am trying to implement the ***'smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_sender_login_mismatch'*** rule, but this does not allow me use the escaped @ characters in **/etc/postfix/virtual**. If I try that I get this **error**:

```
Sender address rejected: not owned by user test@domain.nl
```

---

**File: /etc/postfix/virtual**

```
...
test@domain.nl test\@domain.nl
other@domain.nl other\@domain.nl
```

---

**File: /etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
...
smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_sender_login_mismatch
```